# Can't get the attribute _id out of a mongoose object using NextJs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm using mongodb and I try to get the id of a reservation by calling the attribute `reservation._id` inside my page after fetching the data. When I try to print reservation._id, I only get "undefined".

Here is my GET function for context:

```
import mongoose, {Schema, model, models} from "mongoose";

const ReservationSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
       type:  String,
       required : true
    },
    status : {
       type:  Boolean,
       required : true
    },
    salle : {
       type:  Boolean,
       required : true
    },
    image : {
       type:  String,
       default: "/salle_mix.png"
    },
})

const Reservation = models.Reservation || model('Reservation', ReservationSchema);

export default Reservation;
```

And for more context, my mongoose schema:

```
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import Reservation from "@models/reservation";

export const GET = async(request)=>{
    try {
        await connectToDB();

        const reservations = await Reservation.find({});
        return new Response(JSON.stringify(reservations), {status: 200})
    } catch(error){
        console.error("Error fetching reservations:", error);
        return new Response("Failed to fetch all reservations", {status: 500})
    }

}
```

Then I'll call my GET function:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchReservations = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/api/reservation');
            const data = await response.json();
            setReservations(data);
        }
        fetchReservations();
    })
```

And I'll try to access the data using:

```
return (
            <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-7">
                {data.map((reservation) =>(
                    <Reservation_Card
                        key = {reservation._id}
                        name = {reservation.name}
                        status ={reservation.status}
                        salle = {reservation.salle}
                        image = {reservation.image}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
```

But even when I call `data._id` before that I get "undefined".

I've already tried converting the id using `.toString()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you update your question with how you are calling the GET function and how you are then trying to access your `reservations` returned by the GET you posted?

Comment: Where is `reservation._id` ?

Comment: I've added clarifications

Comment: What does your `useState()` look like? Seems odd that you're using `data.map()` and not `reservations.map()`